# Perl Open In Unix root directory

Tags: perl

Is it impossible to open a file for writing in the Unix root directory ("/") with Perl open?

Comment: No, but you need to be running as a user which has the right permissions to write there.

Answer (score 5):

So long as you have the appropriate permissions from the filesystem, then you can open any file.

If an `open` fails, then `$!` will contain the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not impossible.  Just to add more context, I believe most of the files in the root directory of Unix/Linux systems are by default writeable only by the root user.  So unless you have files that belong to other users in "/", your perl script will likely have to be run as root.